# Order By in JPQL query on a @ElementCollection annotated map

Tags: java, hibernate, jpql

In my `@Entity` annotated `Course` class, I have the following `@ElementCollection` annotated map:

```
@ElementCollection
private Map<Student, Double> courseStudAndAvgStudGrade;
```

In the example above, Student is another `@Entity` annotated class and the value is the average grade from a `Course` for each `Student`. I'm trying to **write a query in JPQL** that would retrieve all the entries of this map and **sort by entry value in descending order.**

So far, I have the following:

```
TypedQuery<Tuple> query =
              em.createQuery("SELECT KEY(map), VALUE(map) "
                      + "FROM Course c JOIN c.courseStudAndAvgStudGrade map WHERE c.id = :id", Tuple.class);
```

This retrieves the values correctly in a `Tuple` for the desired `Course`, however adding `ORDER BY VALUE(map) DESC` to the JPQL query results in a `java.sql.SQLException: Subquery returns more than 1 row`.

Is it possible to do `ORDER BY` on a map in JPQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JPA/Hibernate does not require the `VALUE` qualifier i.e. it's actually just there for completeness. Try the following query:

```
em.createQuery("SELECT KEY(map), map FROM Course c JOIN c.courseStudAndAvgStudGrade map WHERE c.id = :id ORDER BY map DESC", Tuple.class);
```